# Visual Studio 2010 hangs during debugging of C++ / CLI (mixed mode ) projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, freeze, mixed-mode

After Google the issue i found that it was [reported already](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/666572/visual-studio-2010-hangs-during-debugging-of-c-cli-mixed-mode-projects) but nothing useful yet from MS. I wonder if any one found a work around it?

Comment: VS2010 hangs and crashes a lot

Comment: Only for c++. i have been using it intensively for c# and I'm very happy with it.

Comment: 99% of my use is C++ ... I don't know what they did but it's horrid. Have you tried using a remote debugger or another instance of visual studio and attaching to the process?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use windbg. You'll have to do a lot of commands by hand, but it's the best debugger out there. It handles mixed mode without any major issues. It has a bit of a learning curve, but it's very versatile.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio's debugger is really not reliable when debugging mixed mode applications. Taken from my answer here [#5965771](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955714/debugging-in-mixed-mode-with-native-c-managed-c-cli-and-c-solution/5965771#5965771):

- If you're trying to debug a piece of native code try to use a native project as the debugger start-up application. Under the project settings, "Debugging" tab set the "Debugger Type" to "Mixed", for us this helped sometimes (the native project can be a DLL for example, simply set your main Exe as debugging target in the project settings);

OR, as already mentioned in another answer: Use WinDbg! With it you can debug both managed/unmanaged mixed code applications much more reliably.

Answer (score -1):

use a different debugger, or don't use the debugger at all, just trace to a file or insert breakpoints in the code with inline assembly language.

Comment: Thanks but do not use a debugger is not an option.