# Strange Behavior of a Program

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks

I have the following structure of the code :

```
[code 1]
cout << some_string << endl
cout << some_string << endl
cout << some_string << endl
cout << some_string << endl
cout << some_string << endl
[code 2]
```

When I remove `cout` statements, code 2 gives different output when it gives when `cout` statements are present. Is this an indication of some memory leak?

The specific example is from stitching_detailed.cpp of OPENCV. I have the following chunk of code:

```
// code 1 - edit added cameras initialization
vector<CameraParams> cameras(0);
HomographyBasedEstimator estimator;
theRNG().state = 0;
estimator(features, pairwise_matches, cameras);
for (size_t i = 0; i < cameras.size(); ++i)
{
    theRNG().state = 0;
    Mat R;
    cameras[i].R.convertTo(R, CV_32F);
    cameras[i].R = R;
    LOGLN("Initial intrinsics #" << indices[i]+1 << ":\n" << cameras[i].K());
}
// cout statements
for (size_t i = 0; i < cameras.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << cameras[i].aspect << endl;
    cout << cameras[i].focal << endl;
    cout << cameras[i].K() << endl;
    cout << cameras[i].ppx << endl;
    cout << cameras[i].ppy << endl;
    cout << cameras[i].R << endl;
    cout << cameras[i].t << endl;
}
// code 2
theRNG().state = 0;
Ptr<detail::BundleAdjusterBase> adjuster;
if (ba_cost_func == "reproj") adjuster = new detail::BundleAdjusterReproj();
else if (ba_cost_func == "ray") adjuster = new detail::BundleAdjusterRay();
else
{
    cout << "Unknown bundle adjustment cost function: '" << ba_cost_func << "'.\n";
    return -1;
}
theRNG().state = 0;
Mat_<uchar> refine_mask = Mat::zeros(3, 3, CV_8U);
if (ba_refine_mask[0] == 'x') refine_mask(0,0) = 1;
if (ba_refine_mask[1] == 'x') refine_mask(0,1) = 1;
if (ba_refine_mask[2] == 'x') refine_mask(0,2) = 1;
if (ba_refine_mask[3] == 'x') refine_mask(1,1) = 1;
if (ba_refine_mask[4] == 'x') refine_mask(1,2) = 1;
adjuster->setRefinementMask(refine_mask);
adjuster->setConfThresh(conf_thresh);

(*adjuster)(features, pairwise_matches, cameras);
```

If I remove `cout` statements, cameras[x].focal is NaN. If I keep `cout` statements, the cameras[x].focal has valid values.

I know its not a lot to give, but I'm at the end of my effort to debug it. Any help debugging the problem is appreciated. Even if you know a standard way of debugging it, please let me know.

Comment: `Is this an indication of some memory leak?` Nope, [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Have you used a debugger to step through the lines and watch the variables?

Comment: @Torbjörn I'm using CLI/C++ interface for this C++ code. Debugging C#, C++/CLI, C++ code is way too difficult in Visual Studio. In short, I can't step through it.

Comment: What does "cameras[i].K()" do in that loop? Could focal be set as a side effect?

Comment: @ubaabd interesting, as VS is arguably the finest user-mode Windows debugger on the planet. I'm surprised MS made is so difficult to debug  a paradigm of their own creation. Wow.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes it is. I tried to follow a few answers on SO, but to no use. So finally, I started debugging with cout statements. [Ref 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955714/debugging-in-mixed-mode-with-native-c-managed-c-cli-and-c-sharp-solution)

Comment: @geipel cameras[i].K() returns a MAT object.

Comment: Can you show us where you initialize your cameras ?

Comment: @Sunreef I have added the cameras initialization code. Its right in the start of [code 1] chunk.

Comment: Where do you initialize your focal length ? In the K() function ?

Comment: @Sunreef `cameras` are declared as empty `vector` of type `CameraParams`. I have added that line. `HomographyBasedEstimator` operates on it in the line `estimator(features, pairwise_matches, cameras);`

Comment: @ubaabd *Debugging C#, C++/CLI, C++ code is way too difficult in Visual Studio.* -- I don't know what you're doing wrong, but this is not true.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It must be some problem on my end. I tried a few solutions given on SO, but I'm unable to step through my C++ side. The only code I'm able to step through is C# and C++/CLI.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie both C++/CLI and C++ sides are DLL projects. When I try to step into my C++ function, it just steps out of it with the results.

Comment: @ubaabd -- You either 1) didn't set the "Debug" option in the C# project to "Native Debugging", or 2) your DLL doesn't have debug symbols loaded, or 3) The C++ DLL you think you're debugging isn't the one that is being loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expose bugs by removing seemingly unrelated code, that's almost always a sign of *undefined behavior* bugs present somewhere in your program, that are dormant until your program memory layout changes ever so slightly.

As for what kind of undefined behavior that would cause such bugs, there are multiple options. Uninitialized pointers, pointers pointing at the wrong place, array out-of-bounds bugs etc etc.

(You can also get this kind of behavior from stack overflow, though it seems unlikely in this case.)

Comment: Since OPENCV is not in my hands so can't really debug any uninitialized pointers in OPENCV. Is there a way that I can fix this (even any dirty trick that works). I need to deliver the code ASAP.

Comment: I doubt OpenCV gives uninitialized pointers. You should re-read the documentation/tutorial. Most likely you missed a point.

Comment: @ubaabd No idea, sorry. This is really a very broad topic, there could be any bug anywhere in your code causing this. I'd take an extra look at all variable initializations, ensure there's no uninitialized variable being used. A static code analyser is very handy for finding such bugs.

Comment: @Lundin I have only used vectors and Mat objects in my code. Nowhere did I try to manage the memory myself. I'll still look into uninitialized variables though.

Comment: @Lundin Apparently there was a pointer `Ptr<FeaturesFinder> finder;` that the original OPENCV example was freeing using `finder->collectGarbage();`. I added the line `finder.release();` in front of it and that seems to solve the problem. I'm not sure whether this is actually the reason. I have called release() function after all Ptr objects.